# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer. Help needed on how to deallocate all memory

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I get a **munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer** error from my code below. I can't find anything similar to my code here on Stackoverflow, so I am basically out of clue on how to proceed.
I think I know why I get it these errors.
From what I understand, I will not be able to release all memory even if I free all dynamically allocated memory due to my code.
The problems, in my case, seem to stem from(?) sending data to csv-files, which apparently results in memory leaks.

I have tried different ways to solve this problem, but I haven't been able to do so.

How I should change my code to be able to de-allocate all memory and, if possible, perhaps show a cookie cutter example on how to avoid these problems in the future.

All help is appreciated.

**Stylized Code**:

```
    #define RAWR      429000000
    #define RAWC      5
    #define SUBR      43200000
    #define SUBC      11
    #define PROR      10000
    #define PROC      7200
    
    void f1read(double *raw, char *filename);   //creates raw from csv file
    void f1print(double *raw);                  //prints file to screen

    void f2sample (double *raw, double *subset);  //creates a subset from raw
    void f2print (double *subset);                //print subset to screen
    void f2csv (double *subset, char *filename);  //print subset to csv
    
    void f3sampleN (double *sampleN, double *pointK, double *pointS, ); //evaluation
    void f3printK (double *pointK);             //print pointK to screen
    void f3printS (double *pointS);             //print pointS to screen
    void f3csvK (double *pointK, char *filename);      //print pointK to csv
    void f3csvS (double *pointS, char *filename);      //print pointS to csv
    ....


    int main(void) {     
       ...
    for (n = 0; n < 500; n++) {
       double *raw = calloc(RAWR * RAWC, sizeof(double));   
       double *subset = calloc(SUBR * SUBC, sizeof(double)); 
       double *pointK = calloc(PROR * PROC, sizeof(double));
       double *pointS = calloc(PROR * PROC, sizeof(double)); 
       ....     
       
       char *data1 = dataFile1[n];      // name of the file
       char *data2 = dataFile2[n];  
       ....        

       f1read(rawData, char data1);      //data1 = name of original csvfile
       f1print(rawData);                 //print rawData to screen

       f2sample(rawData, sampleData);    //build sampleData from rawData
       f2printSample(sampleData);        //print sampleData to screen
       f2csvSample(sampleData, data2);   //print sampleData to csv-file                                                          

       f3sampleN(sampleN,pointK, pointS);          
       f3printK(pointK);
       f3printS(pointS);    
       f3csvK (pointK, data3);   
       f3csvK (pointS, data4);   
       ....

       free(rawData);
       free(sampleData);
       free(pointK);
       free(pointS);
       ....
     }
```

Comment: Do you check the pointer returned by `calloc()` for success every time?  Related -- I see your code does a `free()` on `rawData` and others at the end... are we sure all of these were allocated successfully?

Comment: You're most likely corrupting memory somewhere. Add `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to your compile command line and see where that takes you when you run it.

Comment: Please revise question with a [mre] not incomplete snippets.

Comment: Prefer passing a variable instead of a type to `sizeof`:  `sizeof *raw` instead of `sizeof(double)`.  The former is purely mechanical and it leads to less code duplication.

Comment: `f1read(rawdata, char data1)` looks wrong to me.

Comment: I did run -fsanitize=address,undefined and I got the following error:==34285==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x7add39033800 at pc 0x5641610fa0c4 bp 0x7ffe8f2ba950 sp 0x7ffe8f2ba940

Comment: 34285==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x7add39033800 at pc 0x5641610fa0c4 bp 0x7ffe8f2ba950 sp 0x7ffe8f2ba940
WRITE of size 8 at 0x7add39033800 thread T0
    #0 0x5641610fa0c3 in f2makeSample /home/.../.../Kod/C/UrdAnalys/UrdFX_3.0/main.c:608
    #1 0x5641610f7e1f in main /home/.../.../.../C/UrdAnalys/UrdFX_3.0/main.c:447
    #2 0x7ae0f6429d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)
    #3 0x7ae0f6429e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f)
    #4 0x5641610f7484 in _start (/home/.../.../.../C/UrdAnalys/UrdFX_3.0/bin/main+0x32484)

Comment: Moreover, the program crashes at the second function. The size of the imported CSV-data is about 212 MB. The f2makeSample array is about 45M x 12, i.e. less than 500 MB

Comment: @greg spears, No, I am not sure. How do I check that? Besides doesn't the heap buffer overflow indicate the problem should be that I allocated to much space? I am out of clues here.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the error. I tried to free a memory that wasn't allocated at the same time as I didn't free a memory that was allocated.
Stupid mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience.